# Replace fragment not replacing the content?

Tags: android

XML code containing framelayout which is being replaced

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_new"
        android:onClick="new_booking" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"           
        android:src="@drawable/icon_history"
        android:onClick="click_history" />
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_rates" 
        android:onClick="click_rates"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"           
        android:src="@drawable/icon_customer_care"
        android:onClick="click_customer" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code for replacing the above frame with another frame ContactFragment.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =       getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(5, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

content frame is not being replaced rather overridden...i.e i am able to see images which are contained in contentframe...even after transaction is called.

Comment: Your not replacing any framelayout contents, whether what your doing is loading another fragment in it, if you want do this there is two way: 1) make default layout contents to a fragment and while loading another fragment, just delete the first one. 2) Remove all views before loading the fragment to this framelayout.

Comment: yes iam replacing whole fragment(content fragment) with another fragment(Conatct Fragment)..but the content of Content fragment is also visible. according to me it should be replaced

Comment: Your not removing the previously loaded fragment, that's why the contents of the previous fragment is shown, try this : `transaction.remove(removeFragment); transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);`. Let's me know if it's work.

Comment: but replace works same as remove and add the fragment in same line...and iam using transaction.replace

Comment: Just use once, and let me know.

Comment: thanks for help but i found other way around...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the right way of doing this..but it worked.
you have to do following
Create the instance of FrameLayout in java file.

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
```

then use this as folllows:

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =       getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    frameLayout.removeAllViews();
    ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(5, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

frameLayout.removeAllViews() this line removes all the xml components which are there in the frameLayout